# Importing unknown java class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ormlite

I am new to Java! Doing [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-ormlite-with-sqlite-database-tutorial/) tutorial, and on each

```
import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
```

line I get an `unused import statement` error. But it is used as a super class. What can I do?

Using `Android Studio`. Dragged files into `Android Studio`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You would need two additional libraries apart from Android support library and those are:

    ormlite-android-x.jar
    ormlite-core-x.jar

You may download the latest copies either from the libs directory of the attached source code or from the below URL:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ormlite/files/releases/com/j256/ormlite/

You may download both of them and put into the “libs” directory of the project.

Comment: @Divyesh I have added that two files.

Comment: Try to `Build -> Clean/Rebuild Project`

Comment: `Rebuild` done, not helped

Comment: @Janos > Which IDE ? How did u add this two libs ?

Comment: Using `Android Studio`. Dragged files into `Android Studio`.

Comment: Have you Right click on your jar and choose `add as Library`

Comment: You really need to RTFM dude.  The getting started page will have saved you a lot of time.  This is like your 3 or 4th question that would have been answered if you looked at the docs (+android docs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add these jars as library, to do so right click on these jars and select `Add as Library`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and Include this Libraries in libs folder under app

   - ormlite-android-x.jar
   - ormlite-core-x.jar
2. In **android studio** right click on this **.jar** files and click **Add as library**